# Cell size won't update after contained UITextView height is updated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have cell size set to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in my table. My cell constraints are set like so:

[image]

First image above shows how 'cellView' is pinned. Inside cell view and pinned to the top and sides is the text view:

[image]

When I create a cell I calculate a new height for the textView frame based on the content:

```
cell.textView.sizeToFit()
cell.textView.layoutIfNeeded()
let height = cell.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(cell.textView.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max)).height
cell.textView.frame.size.height = height
```

I have tested this code above and it works. It correctly sets the new frame height for the textView. However my cell size isn't showing correctly. As the textView is pinned to the sides of the cell and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is set it should resize to fit the textView frame. It is just staying the same size as the design in the interface builder. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Any pointers would be really appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Try by removing height constraint  and code for calculating new height.

Comment: If you're constraints are set properly, then you dont have to do any of the frame setting and all. I think its issue with constraints.

Comment: @Adithya UITextView will auto resize to fit content? I thought it wouldn't because it has scroll so the content fits regardless.

Comment: @Kex Yea, you may be right on that. If you are increasing the height of TextView, why not just use UILabel? For UILabel will calculate internal size automatically.